# nearly sorted array using heap sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

I have an assignment and here is the question I struggle.

> We are given an unsorted array A[1…n]. Now, imagine its sorted
> version. The unsorted array has the property that each element has a
> distance of at most k positions, where 0<k<=n, from its index in the
> sorted version. For example, when k is 2, an element at index 5 in the
> sorted array, can be at one of the indices {3,4,5,6,7} in the unsorted
> array. The unsorted array can be sorted efficiently by utilizing a
> Min-Heap data structure.
>
> Question : . Generate  the array sizes of 100,1000,10000,100000 and
> note running times, show results.

I have implemented my solution in java.

here is my running time tables.
in the first table, k values are determined according to the array.
in the second table, k values are hold same.

[running time of the kHeapSort algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZawE.png)

I was struggling about analyzing these tables.I couldn't figure out how array size and k effects the algorithm.Any hint would be helpful.Thank you already.

Comment: Maybe try more data points?

Comment: For a series of values of `k`, say 1, 5, 15, 75, 300, calculate those data points and generate a linear regression line.  See how well the lines fit and compare the lines. What you should get is approximately linear in array size, with a constant proportional to `log(k)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @btilly